# (ReactJs) How include more than one component in another component?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

Edit: This has been solved. In Menu.js I had written "export default MenuChoise;".

I´m new to React. To me, the code below should produce 2 buttons, one with the text "Show content" and the other with the text "Add new book". Instead I get one button with no text at all. Why?

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Menu from './pages/Menu';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Menu text1="Show content" text2="Add new book"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Menu.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuChoise from './MenuChoise';

class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return
          (<div>
            <MenuChoise choisetext={this.props.text1}/>
            <MenuChoise choisetext={this.props.text2}/>
          </div>);
    }
}

export default MenuChoise;
```

MenuChoise.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class MenuChoise extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
          <button type="button" value={this.props.choisetext}/>
        );
    }
}

export default MenuChoise;
```

Comment: Have you tried `<button>{this.props.choisetext}</button>` instead?

Comment: @DanPrince  Yes, I get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The render method for your Menu component is returning `undefined` because you've placed the opening parenthesis after the `return` on the next line.

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return
      (<div>
        <MenuChoise choisetext={this.props.text1}/>
        <MenuChoise choisetext={this.props.text2}/>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Before the browser evaluates your code, it passes through a transformation called Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI), where it tries to work out where there should where to terminate lines of code.

In this case, the ASI adds a semicolon after return, which causes the function to terminate without a return value.

```
  render() {
    return; // <-- asi happens here
      (<div>
        <MenuChoise choisetext={this.props.text1}/>
        <MenuChoise choisetext={this.props.text2}/>
      </div>);
  }
```

There's no way for React to know what happened here, so it can't tell you what the problem was, however, the error message would have been:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Menu.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

This will at least help you understand *where* the problem is coming from.